# Непонятная работа AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Не  работает простейший ajax запрос. При нажатии на кнопку должно отправляться письмо. При нажатии на кнопку срабатывает первый alert. Далее выскакивает второй alert(data) и он пустой, но при этом обработчик test.php не срабатывает. Не работает как с прямым так и с относительным путем. Помогите, я в отчаянии!

Код

```js
function klikaj() {
    alert('ok');
    var name=3;
    var phone=6;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://exmaple.xyz/test.php',
        data: {phone:phone, name:name},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert (data);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Код обработчика
 `echo $_POST['name'];`

`mail("milllanikev@gmail.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3");`

Есть предположение что это из-за единой точки входа расположенной в index.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
    $Page = 'index';
    $Module = 'index';
} else {
    $URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
    $Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
    $Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);
    if (!empty($Module)) {
        $Param = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++) {
            $Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
        }
    }
}
if ($Page == 'index') include('page/index.php');
else if ($Page == 'regreg') include('page/regreg.php');
else if ($Page == 'editproject') include('page/editproject.php');
else if ($Page == 'regcom') include('page/regcom.php');
else if ($Page == 'regprofile') include('page/regprofile.php');
else if ($Page == 'addproject') include('page/addproject.php');
else if ($Page == 'delmember') include('page/delmember.php');
else if ($Page == 'addmember') include('page/addmember.php');
else if ($Page == 'account') include('acc/account.php');
else if ($Page == 'search') include('page/search.php');
else if ($Page == 'comm') include('page/comm.php');
else if ($Page == 'mail') include('mail.php');
```

Comment: А не хотите ли избавиться от else/if? Более читабельный switch/case как раз подойдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно было прописать в index путь к файлу

```
else if ($Page == 'test') include('test.php');
```

А в ajax `url: '/test'`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/145594)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Это сам автор и пишет, поэтому Ваш комментарий может его несколько озадачить :)

Comment: @Yaant ну это стандартный комментарий. Я в целом скорее призываю дать чуть более развернутый ответ, который может быть полезен другим участникам )

Comment: Опишите решение проблемы более детально. Сейчас ваш ответ выглядит, как комментарий.

Answer (score 2):

Никогда не дебажьте так

```
alert (data);
```

всегда дебажьте так

```
console.log(data);
```

И смотрите в консоли.

Далее, смотрите в консоли куда уходит ajax и что возвращает.
Попробуйте просто напрямую зайти на `http://exmaple.xyz/test.php`, чтобы убедиться, что запросы попадают туда куда надо, можно в test.php первой строчкой написать `return "да это я";` чтобы проверить.

Comment: дебажат обычно через `debugger` с точками останова, а не через консоль))

Comment: совет исходя из "alert точно нельзя", "console.log()" - так же быстро и просто + не останавливает скрипт

Comment: Скорее надо корректнее написать не "дебажьте", а "проверяйте". + добавить что-то про дебаг как-раз, имхо

Comment: "дебажте" vs "проверяйте"? В контексте данной задачи автора не вижу разницы. Разве только что слова "дебажте" нет в русском языке. Но думаю это не как не влияет на понимание ответа и его полезности для автора.

Answer (score 0):

Этот код и не будет работать. Наверняка у вас в консоли браузера пишет  $.ajax is not a function. (Консоль браузера открывается по кнопке F12)

Вам сперва надо подключить аякс

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

а затем уже вызывать функции

Впрочем вы не привели коды ошибок, которые у вас в консоли поэтому ответ вам никто внятный не даст.

В файле  http://exmaple.xyz/test.php я рекомендую вам  для теста весь код закоментить и написать лишь 2 проверочных строчки

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```